# Apply filter function on list elements

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I would like to subset my data (lists within a list) with the filter function, where I want to filter based on a list with selected dates.
Applied for one single sublist, it works well, but the upscaling into a for loop for the whole data set causes problems either regarding the indexing or the automatically adding of the sublists to the main list (output is just the last sublist).

The filtering for one list element:

```
library(dplyr)
sublist_1 <- data.frame("value" = rnorm(10), "date" = 1:10, "parameter" = "X")
sublist_2 <- data.frame("value" = rnorm(10), "date" = 1:10, "parameter" = "Y"))
selected_dates_X <- c(3, 5, 7)
selected_dates_Y <- c(4, 6, 8)
df_total <-list("sublist_1" = sublist_1, "sublist_2" = sublist_2)


filtered_sublist_1 <- filter(df_total$sublist_2, 
                             date %in% selected_dates_Y)
```

My unsuccessful try to apply this in for loop, with an added if-statement. I want to create two lists, in which the filtered data is added for parameter X and Y, respectively.

```
df_X <- list()
df_Y <- list()

for (i in df_total) {
  if (i$parameter %in% "X") {
  filtered_sublist_X <- filter(df_total[[i]],
              date %in% selected_dates_X) 
  df_X[[length(df_X) + 1]] <- filtered_sublist_X
  
  } else {
    filtered_sublist_Y <- filter(df_total[[i]],
              date %in% selected_dates_Y) 
  df_Y[[length(df_Y) + 1]] <- filtered_sublist_Y
  }
}
```

As output, I want two datasets, filtered by selected_date for each parameter X and Y.
Maybe this is not an appropriate approach to do this, then feel free to suggest other solutions, maybe with a function and lapply()? (Tried it, but also doesn't work)

Thanks!

Comment: What is `i$parameter` that you are checking? Is it the name of the list? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: My dataset is a modelled time series of soil water content, with one value each day for 140 years. I want to subset my data with determined dates, as I doesn't need all of the time series days. 
In my example, parameter is one of two soil properties which can be X or Y.  Depending on this property, the dates which has to be selected differ, therefore I want to sort by X and Y and then apply the selected_dates X or Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `lapply` approach -

```
filtered_sublist_X <- lapply(df_total, function(x) 
            subset(x, parameter %in% "X" & date %in% selected_dates_X))

filtered_sublist_Y <- lapply(df_total, function(x) 
            subset(x, parameter %in% "Y" & date %in% selected_dates_Y))
```

Comment: How can I apply this on the 840 sublists within my main list "df_total"? Therefore I intended to iterate through the main list with for loop, but the indexing doesn't work.

Comment: `lapply` is like `for` loop. It applies the function (with `function(x)`) to each sublist. Did you try the answer? What did it return to you?